# JavaScript Magnifying glass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I built a magnifying glass in JavaScript, which works well when I click on it or click and dragging it, but it should not hide from the screen.

```
$(".menu-left-preview-box-preview").bind('click', function (e) {
    window.location = "page" + ($(this).index() + 1) + ".html";
});

var native_width = 0;
var native_height = 0;
var magnifyIsMouseDown = false;
$(".magnify").parent().mousedown(function (e) {
    magnifyIsMouseDown = true;
});
$(".magnify").mousemove(function (e) {
    if (magnifyIsMouseDown) {
        if (!native_width && !native_height) {
            var image_object = new Image();
            image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");
            native_width = image_object.width;
            native_height = image_object.height;

        } else {
            var magnify_offset = $(this).offset();
            var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
            var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;

            if (mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0) {
                $(".large").fadeIn(100);

            } else {
                $(".large").fadeOut(100);
            }
            if ($(".large").is(":visible")) {
                var rx = Math.round(mx / $(".small").width() * native_width - $(".large").width() / 2) * -1;
                var ry = Math.round(my / $(".small").height() * native_height - $(".large").height() / 2) * -1;
                var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";

                var px = mx - $(".large").width() / 2;
                var py = my - $(".large").height() / 2;
                $(".large").css({ left: px, top: py, backgroundPosition: bgp });
            }
        }
     }
});

$(".magnify").parent().mouseup(function (e) {
    magnifyIsMouseDown = false;
    $(".large").fadeOut(100);
});
$(".magnify").parent().mouseleave(function (e) {
    $(".large").fadeOut(100);
});

manageSlide();
```

By default the magnifying glass must be there on the screen. The magnifying glass can be dragged and after it's dropped it must remain there at it's dropped position.

On clicking and dragging the magnify glass is working well, but it should not hide from the screen. It should be there on screen.

Provide handle of magnify glass with that circle (in design).

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mohsin80/4ww8efx5/

Comment: Why did you put the JavaScript code inside `script` tags in the HTML field? It's so harder to read and gives you/us no advantage imo.

Comment: i put this in scrip tag then it will not work properly that's why...

Comment: It wont work outside of a script tag because your manually listening to `window.onLoad`. Jsfiddle will wrap your code by default in `onLoad`. In the left hand menu change the drop-down from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>` and you can then take your JS out of a script tag to help others help you. Your also pulling in JQuery through the fiddle so no need to pull it in in a script tag either. Finally if you highlight your code and press shift tab it will auto format it. Properly formatted code helps others read it, in turn helping you. Frankly that fiddle is painful.

Comment: Is it just me or does the magnifying glass actually make the image smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the `if (magnifyIsMouseDown) {` by `if (isDragging) {` and created the following methods:

```
var isDragging = false;
$(".magnify").parent().mouseup(function(e) {
    isDragging = false;
});
$(".magnify").parent().mousedown(function(e) {
    isDragging = true;
});
```

To make a simulated drag event with jQuery.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pedromendessk/4ww8efx5/1/). Hope it helped :)

Comment: hello pedrop mendes i click on magnifier handle then my mouse cursor move to center of magnifier circle but i don't want like this. i want it's draggable on handle and circle both.  working demo:http://jsfiddle.net/mohsin80/4ww8efx5/2/

Comment: this demo work fine in desktop but in mobile device magnifier dragging is not working plz help me.